# Animation function stops at random position

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a question I have an animation function that animates a list of images. When I call the function I give it the amount of frames per second, when it needs to stop and the list element with all the images. But for some reason the animation stops at random position.
Please help.

```
var StartAnimation = function(fps, end, idss){
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var frames = document.getElementById(idss).children;
var frameCount = frames.length;
var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function(){

    if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > end){
        clearInterval(interval);

        $('#'+idss+ '> div > img').css('display','none');

    }

    //animate files
    frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
    frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";

}, fps);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using this code:

```
if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > end){
        clearInterval(interval);
        $('#'+idss).find($('img')).css('display','none');
        $('#'+idss).children().first().css('display','block');
    }
```